# A Verbatim Caret Which Is Copy/Pastable

Tags: fonts, symbols, verbatim, characters

Is there a way to typeset a caret in a verbatim-like environment (`\verb`, `\begin{verbatim}`, or `\texttt`) so that it can be copy/pasted into the terminal?

Comment: what is wrong with `\verb|^|` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I copy/pasted it into the terminal, it showed up as ˆ, instead of ^, and the terminal did not treat it as a caret.

Comment: as always your question would be clearer if you showed a complete small document that shows the problem, and also in this case say what pdf viewer and terminal you are cutting and pasting between

Comment: Seriously consider using `\setmonofont` in `fontspec` to get a desktop font, which could be Latin Modern Mono or Computer Modern Typewriter, and setting your terminal to UTF-8 mode if it isn’t already. In Windows, the command is `chcp 65001`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was my use of the `lmodern` package.  The Computer Modern Typewriter font copies the caret to the terminal just fine.

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\begin{document}
Latin Modern Typewriter (too small): {\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont\^{}}, 
Computer Modern Typewriter (just right): {\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont\^{}}
\end{document}
```

[image]